# Como reemplazar un un string si el numero es menor que 5

Tags: javascript

// Quisiera saber como se podria hacerta funcion, soy nueva en esto de la programacion

```
funtion(string){
  //La funcion llamada 'fakeBinary' recibe como argumento un string con numeros
 // y debe devolver un string en donde se remplaza los numeros menores de 5 con '0'
 // y los numeros iguales o mayores a 5 con '1'
// Por ej:
 // fakeBinary2('5627') devuelve "1101"
// fakeBinary("729") devuelve "101"
// Tu código aca:
}
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Has intentado algo?

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. En [es.so] no hacemos las cosas por los demás. Debes intentarlo, y mostrar, mediante un [mcve], tu código, explicando dónde tienes problemas. Saludos

Comment: Si, con charAt y una condicional pero no me sale

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 esta lista te será de ayuda; una pregunta bien enfocada es una pregunta medio resuelta. Por otro lado, sin intentos de los que preguntan, las chances de obtener negativos, cierre de preguntas y silencio, son sumamente altos. La situación es totalmente diferente cuando hay intentos e investigación en la pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function fakeBinary(string) {
    string = string.split(''); // Separa el string en un array
    aux = ''; // Crea un auxiliar para almacenar el resultado final
    string.forEach(function(e) { // repite por la cantidad de caracteres del string
        aux += e < 5 ? 0 : 1 // en el resultado final si el caracter seleccionado es menor a 5 agraga 0, sino, agrega 1
    });
    return aux; // devuelve el resultado final
```

}

Comment: Responder preguntas mal formuladas y / o responder sólo con código, es considerado de baja calidad. Con tu respuesta promueves la sinvergüenzura de otros y no les ayudas, al contrario les perjudicas. Te invito a leer [answer].

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).